# Lectura y escritura en un fichero con PHP

Tags: php

Buenas tengo una duda sobre la edición de un fichero de texto, resulta que por defecto tenemos visitas.txt con el valor 0.

Cada vez que actualizamos el programa PHP tiene que ir incrementando este valor en 1 y visualizandolo por pantalla.

He pensado en el siguiente código.

```
<?php
   $f1 = 'visitas.txt';
   $counter = file_get_contents($f1);
   echo 'Esta es la visita número '.++$counter;
   $h1 = fopen($f1, 'w');
   fwrite($h1, $counter);
   fclose($h1);
?>
```

El problema es me piden que abra el fichero tanto de escritura como de lectura en el fopen y vaya actualizando el valor a partir del 0 y así mismo mostrarlo por pantalla. ¿Alguna idea para hacerlo sin utilizar el file_get_contents?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido. No sé si se trata de un ejercicio o si es algo para usarlo realmente en un sitio web. Si es para un uso real no te recomendaría guardar las visitas en un archivo por muchos motivos. Por ejemplo: ¿cómo piensas manejar las visitas concurrentes, por ejemplo, que en el mismo instante accedan al sitio `n` visitantes, quedarán todos registrados? ¿Cómo se van a manejar las visitas por cada URL en el hipotético caso de querer mostrar cuántas visitas tiene cada URL del sitio? ¿Cómo se va a manejar el concepto mismo de *visita* (refrescar la página 100 veces no equivale a 100 visitas)? ...

Comment: ... Yo recomendaría usar herramientas como Google Analytics. Nada más registras el sitio en dicha plataforma y luego puedes programar código usando la API para manejar de una manera real y fácil la cantidad de visitas al sitio. Además, tienes la posibilidad de mostrar visitas globales, visitas por URL, por países, regiones, tipo de dispositivo, etc, etc, etc. Puedes echar una ojeada [aquí](https://www.deiverbum.org) si observas abajo a la derecha donde dice `MÁS VISTOS ESTA SEMANA`, son datos tomados de GA. Y si accedes a cualquier URL te mostrará las visitas a esa URL en específico.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Cedano, es interesante saberlo! Si, esto es un ejercicio de clase que nos han mandado y no consigo sobreescribir el valor y al mismo tiempo mostrarlo por pantalla sin utilizar el file_get_contents

Comment: puedes usar fread http://www.hackingwithphp.com/8/1/3/fopen-and-fread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que manejaría un contador cuyo valor se registraría en el archivo sería este:

<kbd>Fuente: [Esta respuesta de Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20540673/5587982)</kbd>

```
$file="visitas.txt";
// Abrir el archivo para lectura 
$fp = fopen($file, "r"); 

// Obtener el valor actual 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 

// Cerrar el archivo 
fclose($fp); 

// Agregar 1 al valor actual 
$count = $count + 1; 


// Actualizar el valor en el archivo 
$fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $count); 

// Cerrar el archivo 
fclose($fp); 

// Mostrar el total de visitas, si fuera necesario 
echo "<p>Total de vistas: " . $count . "</p>";
```

---

Hay otras técnicas, pero en estos casos no se guarda en el fichero un número total de visitas. Lo que hacen estas técnicas es ¡guardar el total de visitas en el tamaño del archivo!

<kbd>Fuente de ambos métodos: [Esta respuesta de Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243172/5587982)</kbd>

**1. Aumentando por cada visita el tamaño del archivo:**

```
$file="visitas.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r+");
while(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // da acceso exclusivo al archivo
   //Espera mientras ocurre el bloqueo
}

$counter = intval(fread($fp, filesize($file)));
$counter++;

ftruncate($fp, 0);      // trunca el archivo
fwrite($fp, $counter);  // escribe el dato
fflush($fp);            // flush de la salida antes de quitar el bloqueo
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // quita el bloqueo

fclose($fp);
```

**2. Escribiendo un `1` en el archivo cada vez que hay una visita:**

Hay otro método parecido, que va escribiendo un `1` cada vez que ocurre una visita y como el anterior, el total de visitas se calcula en base al tamaño en bytes del archivo:

```
file_put_contents( $file, '1', FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX );

// Muestra el total de visitas si fuera necesario
echo "Total de visitas: ".filesize($file);
```

En este caso, tu archivo se irá llenando de `1`, según vayan visitando el sitio. Cuando haya un millón de visitas habrá 1 millón de `1`  y el tamaño del archivo será 1 millón de bytes.

Aquí lo tenemos con 16 visitas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias nuevamente compañero! El primer método es el que se me había ocurrido desde el principio pero pensé que hacerlo así era incorrecto, entonces lo usaré para ir aumentando el valor. Una cosa más, en el primer código por cada fopen haces un fclose, ¿sería correcto no poner el fclose después del fopen de lectura al estar sobreescribiendo el valor del handler con el fopen de escritura? y ya al final solo pones un fclose? Gracias!

Comment: @0xefro me parece que probé eso y lo que hacía era escribir el valor de `$count` al lado del valor ya existente. Quizá se podría hacer lo que quieres, pero truncando el archivo o borrando su contenido para escribir el nuevo. No sé que sería más costoso y más susceptible de error en la práctica, si hacer eso o cerrar y abrir el archivo de nuevo para actualizar el contador... sería cuestión de probar.